# Combine google sheet tab data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently I have information across 12 tabs for products, with each tab representing a month

Is there a way that I can import this information, as it is added, to another sheet containing everything for the year?

I've tried using importrange( ) but the issue was that arrays would overlap, giving the following error message

`Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in A95.`

Is there any formula I can use to take the data from these individual tabs and have them combine onto a master tab? Alternatively, if I could have all the data on a master tab and send them to the relevant tab month.

Comment: Can you share your spreadsheet without sharing private information?

Comment: I have the same use case :) You can use IMPORTRANGE inside a QUERY formulae; if you could perhaps share a dummy sheet, I could help out accordingly.

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bnOp4tUsvsNhmAB8w4MKKN4UnGvG24kEBJ8zx55-uN8/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is a dummy spreadsheet - I'll give the Query formulae a try now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way that comes to my mind would be to have a 'global' tab, and then have each monthly tab query the data from the it. To do so, the formula you could use would look like the following (given your example sheet):

`=QUERY(Total!A2:F7, "select * where MONTH(B)+1=6")`

This one would filter the rows that have their date in June.

Otherwise, if your prefer to have a 'global' tab built from the monthly tabs, you could use a GAS custom function such as the following:

```js
function MYFUNC() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets();
  var numSheets = sheets.length;
  var result = [];
  for (var i=0; i<numSheets-1; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
    // Remove header from the datarange
    dataRange = dataRange.offset(1, 0, dataRange.getHeight()-1);
    result = result.concat(dataRange.getValues());
  }
  return result;
}
```

This will import and concatenate the data from all the sheets but the last one (Total) and concatenate it. You just have to set it as follows:

[image: example sheet]

Comment: Thank you - this is a solution I was working for

```=QUERY(Total!A2:F7, "select * where MONTH(B)+1=6")```

I can now maintain a total sheet and have the query function allocate it to the correct month

Comment: @david Glad to hear! Please consider upvoting/accepting my answer if that helped you out (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, upvoted it but I'm new enough here that it doesn't display it publicly